# C - simple linked list delete first element which contains 'k'

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, erase

I want to delete the element in a simple linked list which contains a 'k'.
I am able to get the 'k' in `name = popIfK(&kopf);`
Now in the function `popIfK(...)` I have to point with the element before on the element after. How do I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct V_LISTE
{
    char vorname;
    struct V_LISTE *nachfolger;
};
struct V_LISTE *insert(struct V_LISTE *list, char key)
{
    struct V_LISTE *newElement;
    newElement = (struct V_LISTE *) malloc(sizeof(struct V_LISTE));
    newElement->vorname = key;
    newElement->nachfolger = list;
    list = newElement;
    return list;
}


char popIfK(struct V_LISTE **kopf)
{
    char *returnVal;
    struct V_LISTE *kElement;
    kElement = (*kopf)->nachfolger;
    while (kElement->vorname != 'k')
    {
        kElement = kElement->nachfolger;
    }
    returnVal = &kElement->vorname;
    // Nun muss das Element davor auf das danach zeigen 
    // und Speicher von dem Element mit k muss freigegeben werden
    free(*kopf);
    *kopf = kElement;
    return *returnVal;
}

void ausgabe(struct V_LISTE *list)
{
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c", list->vorname);
        list = list->nachfolger;
    }
    printf("\n");
} 

int main()
{
    struct V_LISTE *kopf;
    kopf = (struct V_LISTE *) malloc(sizeof(struct V_LISTE));

    kopf->vorname = 'n';
    kopf->nachfolger = NULL;

    kopf = insert(kopf, 'n');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'a');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'k');
    kopf = insert(kopf, ' ');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'o');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'l');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'i');
    kopf = insert(kopf, 'T');

    ausgabe(kopf);
    printf("Nun müsste ein 'k' kommen:\n");
    name = popIfK(&kopf);
    printf("%c\n", name);
    printf("Nun müsste \"Tilo ann\" kommen:\n");
    ausgabe(kopf);
}
```

So my problem is the following:
`ausgabe(kopf)` gives the output: ***Tilo kann***

After using the function `name = popIfK(&kopf);` with the second call of `ausgabe(kopf)` I expect the output: ***Tilo ann***

But what I get as output is: ***kann***

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: So what's the problem? Does your code compile? Does your code do something else than you expected? What is the expected output vs. the actual output? Read this: [ask]

Comment: EDIT: You're right - I described the problem now more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second pointer which follows one node behind `kElement`.  That way, when you find the node you want to delete, you can do something like `prev->nachfolger = kElement->nachfolger`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (kElement->vorname != 'k')
{
    kElement = kElement->nachfolger;
}
```

In this search you should also keep another variable which follows kElement. 
try something like this

```
{
    follower=kElement;
    kElement=kElement -> nachfolger;
}
```

this way after the loop you can modify `follower` .

Answer (score 0):

For starters use English words to name identifiers. Otherwise it is difficult to read your code by other programmers.

Your function definition at least due to the last statement in this code snippet

```
char popIfK(struct V_LISTE **kopf)
{
    char *returnVal;
    struct V_LISTE *kElement;
    kElement = (*kopf)->nachfolger;
    //...
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the function is called for an empty list. It also invokes undefined behavior when the list does not contain a node with the value `'k'`. Or it will not even work when it is the first node that contains the value `'k'`.

Take into account that you should decide what to return from the function if the list does not contain a node with the value `'k'`.

One of approaches is to return for example the character `'\0'`.

If I have understood correctly what you need is the following

```
char popIfK( struct V_LISTE **kopf )
{
    char returnVal = '\0';

    while ( *kopf != NULL && ( *kopf )->vorname != 'k' )
    {
        kopf = &( *kopf )->nachfolger;
    }

    if ( *kopf != NULL )
    {
         returnVal = ( *kopf )->vorname;

         struct V_LISTE *kElement = *kopf;

         *kopf = ( *kopf )->nachfolger;

         free( kElement );
    }

    return returnVal;
}
```

In my opinion the function does not make a great sense. You could write a more general  function that removes from the list a node with the given character value.

Such a function can look the following way

```
int remove( struct V_LISTE **kopf, char vorname )
{
    while ( *kopf != NULL && ( *kopf )->vorname != vorname )
    {
        kopf = &( *kopf )->nachfolger;
    }

    int success = *kopf != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
         struct V_LISTE *kElement = *kopf;

         *kopf = ( *kopf )->nachfolger;

         free( kElement );
    }

    return success;
}
```